# Sails + MySQL reconnect and attempts

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js, waterline

I'm using sails.js and I have a MySQL DB.

My connection and everything working perfectly.

As far as I understand, Sails connect to all DB's on lift.

But what if the connection is lost for 1-2 sec.?
How can I auto-reconnect to the DB, or set attempts to exec the query?

Is there any option to override the function that executing the query, so I can put a try catch and make it recursive or something like that?(of course this change need to be applied to all my servers, so overriding the module itself in the `node-module` folder is a little bit problem..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

sails automatically does this. If you console.log() query result you will see it will print multiple time and it will continue.

Comment: If it hits the catch promise, and I get a connection err it prints nothing to the console. so I can't see it..